# Cucumber: Best practice to call method from one step definition to another step definition

Tags: java, cucumber

I  am working on automating a web service, where I am generating a run time URL and adding it to the context and then continuing with doing PUT on that url.
I have a feature file, stepdefinition and StepDefinitionBase file (this has code to initialize context, add url to context, purge context etc).
My feature file is:

```
Scenario: Validate PUT call     
    Given I create my  PUT url from "/api/test/"
    When method used is Put
    Then Status code equals 200
    And Validate the response
```

StepDefinitionBase class:

```
public class StepDefinitionBase {

    private ExecutionContext context;

    @Before
    public void initializeContext() {
          context = ExecutionContexts.currentContext();
    }

      public void addUrlToContext(String serviceUrl) {
        context.dictionary.put("serviceUrl", serviceUrl);
    }


    @After
    public void clearContext() {

        ExecutionContexts.purgeCurrentContext();
    }
```

Now my flow is : as part of Given , I am having a method in my stepdefinition file which creates a run time URL (which is appending an ID to the "api/test") and then I need to add this generated URL to my context. 
        My context is created(using "Before tags)and updated in another StepDefinitionBase file. But my problem is when I am trying to call the method (which is in StepDefinitionBase file) from  my stepdefinition  file , then it doesn't get invoked but instead the method under "After" tag is called which 
is to do with purging the context, which is not what I want.
        I think  I am not doing it right. Can someone please advise if there is better way to do it. Apreciate the help!

Comment: Can you add the relevant stepdefinition glue code?

Comment: Updating one step definition from other step definition is against cucumber rule book. It should inherit from step definition base class , Context related modification should be happen at base step definition call and all other all tags or test should use that part .

Comment: Please add code that is not working from base file

Comment: Thanks for your response.Added my Stepdefinitionbase class file (note: it doesn't have all lines of code) to my original post. Here the method "addUrlToContext" is not getting invoked from my individual step definition file. I am wondering is there any tag I should be providing for this method in the StepDefinitionBase class ?

Comment: Can someone please help in answering this ?

Comment: @user5252179 The method 'addUrlToContext' is missing the Given or Then or When annotation with the pattern to match.

Comment: Thanks Grasshoper. But I am not calling the 'addUrlToContext' from my feature file but from another step definition file. So I am not sure what annotation should be there.

Comment: Is there a better way to access the methods in the StepDefinitionBase from step definition class ? I am not aware of dependency injection but whatever instance of any other class (like database , StepdefinitionBase etc) I declare in my stepdefinition class, I am getting null pointer exception. Any help please ?